# iOS / SQLite, efficiently updating lots of recoreds with a guid?

Tags: ios, sql, iphone, sqlite

I'm trying to figure out the fastest method of adding a (different) guid to a new field, where there could be thousands of records.

I'm pretty sure SQLite doesn't provide a function which will create a guid. So I'm going need to somehow have to create this for each row.

Ideas I've come up with do far.

1. Simply executing an update query where the field is blank and limit 1. Obviously this is going to be slow even within a transaction.
2. Use cte (common table extension) with a temp table where I build up the values including the guid, the update / join.  However I can't seem to get temp tables to work in iOS, I keep getting a library called out of sequence error.
3. Using inline sub queries with the update query. However I don't know how to identify the rows which require the guid, other than them being blank. I'd need to use recursion, which again would require cte, I believe?

EDIT: Here's my solution, credit to @CL. for the ideas...

```
void newguid(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv)
{
    if (argc != 1 || sqlite3_value_type(argv[0]) != SQLITE_TEXT) {
        sqlite3_result_null(context);
        return;
    }

    @autoreleasepool {
        CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
        NSString *uuidString = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuid);
        CFRelease(uuid);

        sqlite3_result_text(context, [uuidString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    }
}

- (void)createSqlGuidFunction:(sqlite3*)db
{
    if (sqlite3_create_function_v2(db, "newguid", 1, SQLITE_ANY, NULL, &newguid, NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: sqlite3_create_function_v2 error: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not add the guid while you are inserting the rows?

Comment: Thanks @Malik, I'm upgrading my table with a new version of my app. I need the guid as a unique key across all my tables, so I can use it for iCloud / multiple user syncing.

Comment: Ah!. that makes sense. Look at my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#randomblob) says that

> applications can generate globally unique identifiers using this function together with hex() and/or lower() like this:
>
> ```
> hex(randomblob(16))
>
> lower(hex(randomblob(16)))
> ```

But if you want to use a different mechanism to generate the GUID, you can [register your own function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html).

Comment: Thanks that's part of the solution, however this isn't going to create a unique guid, I think true guids are based on a time stamp and include hyphens. Having said that this is a good start. ⭐️ I'm also wondering if this is supported by the iOS SQLite framework.

Comment: Ahhh this is interesting https://gist.github.com/mmarcon/1323584/b0300a9458f7851e45141d9f785346b78f336f5f I will look into this further see if I can come up with a better guid implementation. I will post back in a few days.

Comment: I've added my solution based on your idea to my question. Thanks. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing something like this

```
ALTER TABLE newTable RENAME TO oldTable;
CREATE TABLE newTable (//Define your columns here along with the GUID column);
```

Then you can select all the values from oldTable and insert into newTable along with the GUID. Once you're done, use

```
DROP TABLE oldTable
```

Comment: SQLite doesn't natively support guid as a column type. I'm using varchar with my own function in code to create the guid.

Comment: I know that. By `GUID column`, I mean the column which will store the `GUID` values not the type of the column

Comment: So how would I get a unique guid in each row? I'd need to run individual insert queries? Which is one of the performance bottlenecks I mentioned.

Comment: correct. You'll be using a loop to iterate over the results from `oldTable` and inserting them in the `newTable` along with the guid (which will be created anew on every loop iteration). You can also, look into running this process on a `background queue` if you feel it would be a costly operation

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how that would be any faster than the first method I mentioned? Also I need this process happen before users can use the app, so running in the background isn't going to help.

Comment: No it won't be. But just to point out, your first method will not work since you'll need to alter the table before you can add an additional value for each row.

Comment: Sure, I did say there would be a new field in my opening sentence.

Comment: No, I'm adding it prior to adding the guid